# Calculate Date / Time difference in Bash on macOS

Tags: bash, macos, date

I realize there are tons of questions and answers involving date calculation, but I haven't found a solution to the issue on OS X/macOS. I would like to calculate the time difference between two dates and times, but I must have the syntax incorrect.

```
now=$(date +"%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S")
end=$(date +"Dec 25 2017 08:00:00")
dif=$(date -j -f "%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S" "$end" - "$now")
echo $dif
# Mon Dec 25 08:00:00 MST 2017
```

It returns only the `$end` value, so I'm not sure how to actually calculate the difference in time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The ideal way is convert the current time into EPOCH and also the date you need also in EPOCH and get the diff (This works on `bash` on `macOS Sierra`)

```
dudeOnMac:~ $ date +%s
1512757414
dudeOnMac:~ $ date -j -f "%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S" "Dec 25 2017 08:00:00" +%s
1514169000
```

So now storing in the variables as you wanted

```
end=$(date -j -f "%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S" "Dec 25 2017 08:00:00" +%s)
now=$(date +%s)
printf '%d seconds left till target date\n' "$(( (end-now) ))"
printf '%d days left till target date\n' "$(( (end-now)/86400 ))"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One question, what does the `+%s` actually do?

Comment: It converts what ever the time specified to EPOCH time